# Should I upgrade my CPU even though the load is usually never at 100%?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I'm thinking about getting a new mainboard - mainly because I need an UEFI one.

As of right now I got the Intel Core 2 Quad **Q6600** 2.4GHz and it seems most contemporary mainboards aren't compatible with it?

I'm not an avid gamer but I like to play a game once in a while for which my CPU really *is sufficient* (Crysis 3 is playable) - gaming is not a really my point of interest here though. Instead I'm trying to optimize my PC for **fast multi-tab browsing**.

I find my PC pretty slow for browsing (I have many tabs open in my session and often open up many new ones at the same time). However, when I check the task manager my **CPU load is usually never at 100%** (from time to time it's at 50% without a game on). And now I'm not sure if there would be significant benefits of upgrading my CPU?
Maybe there are other features in newer CPUs (caching etc) that would help improve performance? Or maybe the way the load-allocation to the cores works requires an even better CPU despite the load not being at 100%?

- If you do think that I a new CPU would be of use I'd also be interested in any recommendations on what things to look for to improve browsing performance or specific recommendations.
- And if you think that it wouldn't be a significant enough improvement do you know which good UEFI mainboards are compatible with my CPU? How to find out which are?

Comment: In your case you'll benefit by upgrading your CPU for a few reasons. 1. You'll be able to take advantage of hyper-threading, which your CPU does not have. 2. Your CPU will run at lower TDP, which means it needs less power and will generate less heat. 3. You'll be able to take advantage of the turbo boost technology 4. Higher clock speeds, because why not? 5. Faster bus speeds/bandwidth, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your Cpu is 8-9 year sold. 
The Core2Duo architecture has been replaced by the Core-i architecture. And that is currently in Generation 6, with 7 coming soon.

Nothing will be compatible. It is not even meaningful to compare your antique system with a current system.

Buy a new system and don't look back. Get a minimum of 4 GB RAM and a Core-i 5 or Core-i 7 CPU (any version will do as long as you avoid Core-i3, Celeron and Atom CPU's) and make sure the system has an SSD in stead of a classic harddrive.
It will be fast enough for anything you want to do.

Comment: Alright :D   I'll probably get myself a Intel Core i5-6600. For the RAM I currently have 8GB of 800MHz and I'm not sure if I should upgrade that to 1600MHz DDR3 as well (and I guess DDR4 isn't that much of an improvement to be worth the price?). I've got a hybrid HDD and I think that's enough - do you think it impacts browsing performance much? If so would you recommend getting a small SSD in addition and installing my browser on it? Would that help?

Comment: The CPu determines which motherboards are compatible. The motherboard dictates the type of RAM. DDR3 versus DDR4 RAM isn't really noticeable given a specific CPU. So base the choice of motherboard purely on the other features of the board. Hybrid is good compared to classic HD, SSD is noticeably better than Hybrid. Use a 120 G SSD for C:, keep the hybrid as datadisk. That's the best option.

Comment: Also make sure that you either get the i5-6600 **or** the i5-6600K and a CPU fan. (The K version does not ship with a fan, which I noiticed too late on my current build).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if things are slow then determine the bottleneck. If it is not the CPU then upgrading the CPU will not help much. E.g. it could be that your old system is running of of RAM and is swapping all the time.

You did nto specify an OS, but if you are on windows 7 or higher than running `resmon.exe` can help with this. For BSD and Linux start with `top` and `iotop`.

OK, that was verty generic advice, now two more specific items:

1) Why do you need UEFI? I'll admit it is better firmware than BIOS, but usually [U] EFI is not a key point.

2) A core2 is an old system. No modern modernboard will work with it. If you are going to upgrade then you almost certainly will get a whole new motherboard+CPU+RAM. And with the drives being old moving to an SSD (preferable M.2 NVME) is also desired. That is no longer an upgrade but a move to a whole new system.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm running 64Bit Windows 10. I tried to determine the bottleneck but I'm not sure about it as both RAM and CPU usually aren't at 100%. And I posted this question as I'm not sure if the CPU is slowing performance nevertheless. I need an UEFI because I need a GPT for my hard drives. The drives aren't old.

Comment: If it is not RAM nor CPU then try the [disk] tab. Do not look for speed there but for utilisation. Also check SMART status of a disk (a failing disk often slows down a system. It will be 100% busy without tranfering much data).  Granted, that is a guess, but once which you want to check.